# Docker images as OS for multiple servers

Tags: virtual-machine, docker, containers

I received a rather puzzling question from my lecturer about Docker after doing a presentation on the differences between docker.io and virtual machines. I told him that the main purpose of docker.io is to deploy software applications without the need of a virtual machine's hypervisor.

The question is: Is it possible for Docker to deploy images with CentOS as base to several servers with no OS installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker uses an existing OS kernel that it makes available to the containers, so : No, it cannot run on "bare-metal", you need an underlying OS to provide the kernel.

But it does not have to be CentOS to run CentOS-based containers (as long as it uses a CentOS-compatible kernel).

In addition to that, the docker software itself needs some userland utilities to run, too.

Comment: So there is no possible way for images to act as an OS for bare-metal servers right?

Comment: You need to run Docker to run an image. You cannot run Docker without an OS. Some people provide minimal Linux distributions to act as Docker hosts. You can install one of those.

Comment: It's worth looking at CoreOS, who provide a distro designed for hosting containers.

Comment: @Han Another option is Project Atomic from Redhat (example of a minimal OS designed to host Docker containers), but in fact any Linux OS with docker installed is capable of running a CentOS image.